# Replace non NA values of a column in a dataframe with a constant

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, na

In my `data` below, I want to replace only the **NONE NA** values of column `yi` whose index are given by `ind` by `Tuke_max` value, is this possible (leaving the NA values untouched)?

Fully reproducible code is below.

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilzl/i/master/j.csv")

first_third_QR <- with(data, fivenum(yi, na.rm = TRUE))[c(2,4)]

inter_QR <- with(data, IQR(yi, na.rm = TRUE))

Tukey_min <- first_third_QR[1] - (3 * inter_QR )
Tukey_max <- first_third_QR[2] + (3 * inter_QR )

ind <- with(data, yi < Tukey_min | yi > Tukey_max)

( yi_vec <- with(data, yi[ind]) ) # Replace the none NA `yi` values below in the `data` 
                                  # with Tukey_max (leave NAs untouched)

#[1] 4.122057 3.457194 3.071523 3.545027 4.454427       NA       NA       NA
#[9]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA 4.119231 
#[17] 3.977800 6.412906
```

Comment: `setTmax <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), x, Tukey_max); setTmax(data$y[ind])`; eventually: `data$y[ind] <- setTmax(data$y[ind])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things need to be done, to get the conjuntion of `ind` with the non `NA` and to index by numeric values in order to not have `NA`'s as indices.
A one-liner will do it.

```
data$yi[ which(ind & !is.na(data$yi)) ] <- Tukey_max
```

Comment: A follow-up of interest [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69442055/16762740).